# Show, Show Detail, Present, Present As Segue not available in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode7

I use Xcode 7.2, I've a problem with segue when I try to perform it What I see is current new segue options are not available but instead I still see is deprecated versions of segue like this:

[image: Here is my image]

Answer (score 2):

Show, Show detail and other new segues are available only when you enable Size classes in your storyboard.

You can turn on size classes by selecting your storyboard on the left most panel, going to View > Utilities > Show File Inspector, and clicking the Use Size Classes checkbox in the right panel.

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Xcode "Use Size Classes" is "Use Trait Variations".

Answer (score 0):

Set `embedd in navigation controller` .

Select Ambassodor controller **Xcode -> Editor ->Embedd in -> NavigationControll**

Comment: I already use embed in navigation controller, The application works perfectly on other machine but not on mine.

Comment: Nope still no effect even tried installing beta version 7.3 but no effect

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the image instruction to resolve it. It may be help to you.

image1

[image]

image2

[image]

image3

[image]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zj67das9c1wi85/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-01%20at%206.47.42%20PM.png?dl=0      https://www.dropbox.com/s/8h4c8qttxxeqvby/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-01%20at%206.47.54%20PM.png?dl=0      [STILL no effect]